# Rx.Net ignore certain exceptions but handle rest of the exceptions

Tags: system.reactive

It is easy to handle a particular set of exceptions using the `Catch` operator. How could we ignore certain exceptions but handle the rest in the `Catch` block?

Say for example I would like to let `ArgumentNullException`, `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` and `TimeoutException` exceptions bubble and report an error but for anything else I would like to retry.

The catch version below would catch all the exceptions, and there is no way to selectively ignore some types, as the signature requires it to return a `IObservable<T>`

```
source.Catch<T, Exception>(e=> Observable.Return(default(T)))
```

If I have to retry on certain Exception then I could write something like (I think)

```
source.Catch<T, WebException>(e=> source.Retry())
```

Comment: Add a code example, if you want to do this check in a single command its hard to for example do multiple try. Does this exception happen within the stream ?

Comment: I think I found it, did not pay enough attention to `Throw` signature. here it is 
    
            `return source.Catch<T,Exception>(e =>
            {
                return e is TimeoutException ? source.Retry() : Observable.Throw<T>(e);
            });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very meaningful operator in these situations is `RetryWhen`.

`RetryWhen(selector)` gives you an observable of `Exception`, and expects an observable which, triggers a retry every time it produces a value.

`RetryWhen(e => e)` is equivalent to `Retry()` (all exceptions trigger a retry).

`RetryWhen(e => e.Take(3))` is equivalent to `Retry(3)` (first three exceptions trigger a retry).

Now you can simply transform the inner sequence into one that emits on your desired types of exceptions. For example, to only retry on `TimeoutException`:

```
source.RetryWhen(e => e.Where(exn => exn is TimeoutException))
```